# Why is a WHERE clause to exclude rows in SQLite not working as expected?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to exclude a list of Names in an

I have the table `Names`

```
id| Name    | Surname
---------------------
1 | Michael | Kane
2 | Torben  | Dane
3 | Dinge   | Chain
4 | Django  | Fain
5 | Juliett | Bravo
```

And i have the Table `Excludes`

```
id| Name
-----------
1 | Michael
2 | Torben
```

Now I have two queries:

```
SELECT * From Names, Excludes
WHERE Names.Name = Excludes.Name
GROUP BY Names.Name
```

which results in

```
id | Name    | Surname | id | Name
--------------------------------    
1  | Michael | Kane    | 1  |Michael
2  | Torben  | Dane    | 2  |Torben
```

Now i want to do the exact opposite with `!=` to do the actual purpouse and erase the lines which have the names `Michael` and `Torben` in it

The seconds query is:

```
SELECT * From Names, Excludes
WHERE Names.Name != Excludes.Name
GROUP BY Names.Name
```

The Result is

```
id | Name    | Surname | id | Name
--------------------------------    
3  | Dinge   | Chain   | 2  |Torben
4  | Django  | Fain    | 2  |Torben
5  | Juliett | Bravo   | 2  |Torben
1  | Michael | Kane    | 2  |Torben
2  | Torben  | Dane    | 1  |Michael
```

The Result I would want to have is

```
id| Name    | Surname
---------------------
3 | Dinge   | Chain
4 | Django  | Fain
5 | Juliett | Bravo
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are going to use a `join` (as opposed to `not in` or `not exists`), you want a `left join` and `where` clause:

```
SELECT n.*
From Names n LEFT JOIN
     Excludes e
     ON n.Name = e.Name
WHERE e.Name IS NULL;
```

A simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `left join` instead and filter out `null` values:

```
SELECT Names.* 
FROM Names
LEFT JOIN Excludes ON Names.Name = Excludes.Name
WHERE Excludes.Name IS NULL
```

The `group by` clause seemed meaningless so I removed it.

Another option is to use the `not exists` predicate with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM Names n
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  (SELECT Name FROM Excludes e WHERE e.Name = n.Name)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from Names
where Name not in (select Name from Excludes)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use (not in) with a inner query on Excludes ,
`select * from Names where Name not in (select Name from Excludes)`